# Inverse substitution polar-cartesian

Tags: coordinate-transformation

When I have an expression in polar coordinates and I substitute the definition of $r$ and $\phi$, I get the corresponding expression in polar coordinates. I would like to go back and obtain the same expression now as a function of $r$ and $\phi$, but the code below doesn't simplify the `ArcTan` as I would like:

```
ρ[x_, y_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
Θ[x_, y_] := ArcTan[x, y];
$Assumptions = r > 0 && r ∈ Reals, ϕ ∈ Reals;
ϕ /. r -> ρ[x, y] /. ϕ -> Θ[x, y]
% /. x -> r Cos[ϕ] /. y -> r Sin[ϕ]
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `$Assumptions` isn't used anywhere in the original code because you're just doing replacements. You have to use a function such as `FullSimplify` that actually checks the setting of `$Assumptions`. To decide what functions do this, look for the option `Assumptions` in the `Options` of that function.

With that said, here is how to do the inversion:

```
ρ[x_, y_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];

Θ[x_, y_] := ArcTan[x, y];

$Assumptions = 
  r > 0 && r ∈ Reals && -Pi/2 < ϕ < Pi/2;

ϕ /. r -> ρ[x, y] /. ϕ -> Θ[x, y]

(* ==> ArcTan[x, y] *)

% /. x -> r Cos[ϕ] /. y -> r Sin[ϕ]

(* ==> ArcTan[r Cos[ϕ], r Sin[ϕ]] *)

FullSimplify[%]

(* ==> ϕ *)
```

The only other thing I had to change is to restrict the angle range in `$Assumptions` so that the `ArcTan` can in fact be uniquely inverted.

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to use coordinate transformation for a function. You can do it in this way. Say you have a function `f[x,y]` which you transform into `g[r,q]` and then use the reverse transformation to get back `f[x,y]`.

```
f[x,y]
g[r_, q_] = f[x, y] /. {x -> r Cos[q], y -> r Sin[q]}
f1[x_, y_] = g[r, q] /. {r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], q -> ArcTan[x, y]}
```

> f[x, y]
>
> f[r Cos[q], r Sin[q]]
>
> f[x, y]

Is that what you are looking for?

Also notice that I don't use any form for `f[x,y]`. So it is true for both scalar and vectors.

In your example you get `ArcTan[r Cos[ϕ], r Sin[ϕ]]` instead of `ϕ` because `ArcTan` is bounded within `-Pi/2` to `Pi/2` but your `ϕ` doesn't have such bound. When you use it in another expression, it will give you right answer.

```
Tan[ArcTan[r Cos[ϕ], r Sin[ϕ]]]
```

> Tan[ϕ]

Comment: I want to transform a symbolic expression and not a specific vector

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't work in my case, because I do not want to transform a vector but a scalar expression of (x,y) to the corresponding expression as a function of $(r,\phi)$ and back.

Comment: Also, it doesn't allow me to convert to polar (or cartesian) coordinate the components of a vector in cartesian coordinates (or polar), seperately.